# Get top 50 records from each month(August to November) but only unique ones

Tags: mysql

I have a problem statement where I have to fetch the top 50 **UNIQUE** students from each month(from August to November) on the basis of their score in the monthly exam. The only condition is that the final result must have all unique names which will be a total of 200 names.

This is the DB structure I have.

```
MariaDB [school]> show tables;
+------------------+
| Tables_in_school |
+------------------+
| months           |
| overall          |
| students         |
| scores           |
+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [school]> desc students;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(4)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.17 sec)

MariaDB [school]> desc scores;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(4)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| month_id   | int(4)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| student_id | int(4)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| score      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [school]> desc months;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(4)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

And to solve this problem, I have come with a solution that I'll choose the top 50 students from the month of August, then the top 50 students from the month of September who are not in the top 50 of august and so on. And this is the database query I have come up with

```
SELECT student_id FROM scores WHERE month_id = '3' and student_id NOT IN 
(SELECT id FROM (SELECT student_id FROM scores WHERE month_id = '2' and student_id NOT IN 
(SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM scores WHERE month_id = '1' ORDER by scores.id LIMIT 50) august) 
ORDER BY scores.id limit 50) september) 
ORDER BY scores.id LIMIT 50
```

Clearly, I am not getting the right results. Also, in the final output, I need the unique top 50 from each month from August to November, which means a total of 200 students list. But I am really confused here on how to achieve this. Kindly help me out here.

**EDIT**: I have added the `score` column in `scores` table.

It seems that I have not explained my problem well, hence I am giving you this example.

**EXAMPLE:**

Consider this is how actually the database looks like. And I want the top 3 unique students from each month but the result also must have unique students.

So the top 3 students from October month, should not be in top 3 students from September month. And the top 3 students from September months should not be in top 3 students from the august month.

```
MariaDB [deepracer]> select * from scores limit 15;
+----+----------+------------+-------+
| id | month_id | student_id | score |
+----+----------+------------+-------+
|  1 |        1 |        1   | 8.2   |
|  2 |        1 |        6   | 8.3   |
|  3 |        1 |        7   | 8.8   |
|  4 |        1 |        2   | 9.3   |
|  5 |        1 |        4   | 9.4   |
|  6 |        2 |        1   | 8.4   |
|  7 |        2 |        4   | 8.5   |
|  8 |        2 |        6   | 9.4   |
|  9 |        2 |        5   | 9.7   |
| 10 |        2 |        8   | 9.9   |
| 11 |        3 |        3   | 8.1   |
| 12 |        3 |        4   | 8.2   |
| 13 |        3 |        1   | 9.1   |
| 14 |        3 |        2   | 9.3   |
| 15 |        3 |        9   | 9.4   |
+----+----------+------------+-------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [deepracer]> select * from months;
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | august    |
|  2 | september |
|  3 | october   |
+----+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [deepracer]> select * from students limit 15;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | A    |
|  2 | B    |
|  3 | C    |
|  4 | D    |
|  5 | E    |
|  6 | F    |
|  7 | G    |
|  8 | H    |
|  9 | I    |
| 10 | J    |
+----+------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, the final resultant output should be like this one:

```
+------+-----------+-------+
| name | month     | score |
+------+-----------+-------+
|  A   | august    | 8.2   |
|  F   | august    | 8.3   |
|  G   | august    | 8.8   |
|  D   | september | 8.5   |
|  E   | september | 9.7   |
|  H   | september | 9.9   |
|  C   | october   | 8.1   |
|  B   | october   | 9.3   |
|  I   | october   | 9.4   |
+------+-----------+-------+
```

I hope this is clear enough to understand what is the problem and what should be the solution. Kindly let me know if there is still any confusion.

Comment: I dont understand the purpose of table `overall`? Shouldn't column `score` belong to table `scores`?

Comment: @GMB I have updated db schema as per your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

First, drop your table 'Overall'. Then add a new column 'Score' to your table 'Scores'.

Effectively, each row in table 'Scores' will represent the score for the student for the month, for example this row represents the score for student 1220 for March (3rd month):

ID  MonthID StudentId   Score
--  ------- ---------   -----
3   4       1220        57

Next, since this looks like a homework problem, I'm not going to give you the SQL, but what you need to do is:

1. Write a query that joins students against scores,
2. Restricting the month to august in your where-clause,
3. Selecting distinct student name (i.e. your query output will be a list of names)
4. Test this query and modify until you get the correct name list
5. After you get it working, convert it to a 'derived table' by wrapping it in parenthesis and providing an alias
6. Then, prepend 'Select top 50 name' above your derived table, effectively selecting just 50 of the student names who have scores recorded for August

Comment: Ok, I have made changes in DB schema as per your suggestions. Regarding the steps you suggested, it will only be fetched top 50 students from August month, but not from other months such as September, October, and November. Any idea on how to achieve that as well. In the final output, I need 200 unique student names.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to construct the query in separate parts, each part selecting students for a single month, and combine the results via *Union*. Also, for each part of the query, modify your where-clause to exclude student IDs selected for prior months, along the lines of 'where ID not in (Select ID xxx), where xxx is a the same query selecting top students from prior months.

Comment: I understood your approach, but I am confused on how to prepare where clause.